# Racket// recursive function

Tags: recursion, racket, exponential

as the title says im trying to code recursive for x^n without the expt function. If n is even it should: (x^n/2)^2 otherwise when its uneven x*x(^n-1) and obviously n=0 should be 1.

> (define fast-power
> (lambda (x n)
> (cond
> [(and (number? x) (naturalnumber0? n)) (fast-power-internal x n)]
> [else (error 'fast-power "invalid input.")])))
>
> (define (fast-power-internal x n)
> (cond
> n 0) 1]
> [ (even? n) ???
> else ???
>
> (define (naturalnumber0? n)
> (if (and (isinterger? n) (<= 0 n)) true
> false))
>
> (define (isinterger? x )
> x (floor x)) 0))

on the ??? lines im not sure how to make it recursive with 2 variables. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors with your attempt. Starting with a simple function definition -

```scm
(define (isinterger? x ) x (floor x)) 0))
```

Let's add some line breaks and inline comments -

```scm
(define (isinterger? x )
  x          ; ignored
  (floor x)) ; end of function

0))          ; trailing syntax error
```

Note racket has many built-ins for identifying [number types](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html). `integer?` `natural?` `zero?` `positive?` `even?` etc. You can implement them yourself if you are careful to avoid mistakes but we will use Racket's in the section below.

The problem defines the result in expressions using `^`. I would suggest to first rewrite these without `^`

When `n` is zero -

> *1*

(inductive: `n` is non-zero) When `n` is even -

> *(x^n/2)^2*
> *(x^n/2) * (x^n/2)*
> *f(x, n/2) * f(x, n/2)*  where *f* is `fast-power`

Translated to scheme -

```scm
(* (fast-power x (quotient n 2))
   (fast-power x (quotient n 2)))
```

We can avoid duplicate computation using `let` assignment -

```scm
(let ((r (fast-power x (quotient n 2))))
  (* r r)))
```

(inductive: `n` is non-zero, `n` is non-even) Otherwise `n` is odd -

> *x * x^(n-1)*
> *x * f(x n-1)* where *f* is `fast-power`

Translated to scheme -

```scm
(* x (fast-power x (- n 1)))
```

As for your recursive function, I don't think you need an auxiliary helper. I find it useful to identify error cases before attempting the recursive logic. The `cond` expression is only concerned with the "happy path" of the program -

```scm
(define (invariant condition message)
  (if condition
      (void)
      (error 'invariant message)))

(define (fast-power x n)
  (invariant (number? x) "x must be a number")
  (invariant (natural? n) "n must be a natural number")
  (cond ((zero? n) 1)
        ((even? n)
         (let ((r (fast-power x (quotient n 2))))
           (* r r)))
        (else (* x (fast-power x (- n 1))))))
```

```scm
(fast-power 2 32) ; 4294967296
(fast-power 1.5 4) ; 5.0625
(fast-power 1.5 4.5) ; ⚠️ invariant: n must be a natural number
```

Note: `quotient` returns the integer result of division. `/` returns a number.

Note: Use the `Racket > Reindent` option to format the source code for you automatically.

---

**contracts**

Using `invariant` like I did above is an effective means for handling bad inputs to your programs, however writing code like this can feel like a chore. Racket makes all of this easier with [contracts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contracts.html). Let's see `fast-power` written using a contract -

```scm
(require racket/contract)

(define/contract (fast-power x n)
  (-> number? natural? number?) ; contract
  (cond ((zero? n) 1)
        ((even? n)
         (let ((r (fast-power x (quotient n 2))))
           (* r r)))
        (else (* x (fast-power x (- n 1))))))
```

The contract is explained as -

```scm
(-> 
  number?   ; contract of argument 1
  natural?  ; contract of argument 2
            ; ...
  number?)  ; contract of return value
```

Re-run the program to see the contract enforced -

```scm
(fast-power 2 32) ; 4294967296
(fast-power 1.5 4) ; 5.0625
(fast-power 1.5 4.5) ; ⚠️ fast-power: contract violation
```

Our contract enforces `n` must be a natural number

```
fast-power: contract violation
  expected: natural?
  given: 4.5
  in: the 2nd argument of
      (-> number? natural? number?)
  contract from: (function fast-power)
  ...
```

Note: [define/contract](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contract-func.html) is a [macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html) provided by the `racket/contract`.

Comment: `(eq? x (floor x))` won't work very well for a definition of `integer?`. See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html?q=define%2Fprovide#%28part._model-eq%29 and use `=` instead of `eq?`

Comment: thanks for the review, and exactly why we have to be careful implementing them on our own  i think the post does better without it entirely.